# java - deactivate a listener

Tags: java, swing, listener, jtabbedpane, changelistener

I have a general question regarding listeners.

Lets say I have two `JTabbedPane`s and both have a `ChangeListener`.  They are both displayed and I want them both to show the same  pane (index) so when a user changes the selected pane in one the other changes too.
In brief, one JTabbedPane listener changes the other `JTabbedPane` using `setSelectedTab()`.
Obviously, the first listener will activate the second listener and the second will reactivate the first in an endless operation.

This will be solved with booleans.
Is there a smarter way to do it?
Is there a way to change a tab without triggering the Listener?
Is there a way to activate the listener only when a user changes it and not the code?

Thank you.

BTW: I always have the same questions with buttons. But with buttons I take the code from the listener and put it in a method. when One button needs to activate a button it calls its code. But in JTabbedPane it is different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simple solution is to act only when necessary. For example:

```
if(currentTab != desiredTab) {
  // change tab
}
```

That will prevent an infinite loop.

If you need to be able to switch the behavior on and off, then using a boolean flag isn't a bad way to go about it. The alternative is the remove the listener, using [removeChangeListener](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JTabbedPane.html#removeChangeListener(javax.swing.event.ChangeListener)). The flag may be more performant as it may avoid memory allocation and deallocation, but a lot depends on the other details of your situation.

Comment: Yepp, That will do it. But I will want to change it sometimes without activating the trigger.

Answer (score 3):

share the selectionModel, like

```
 secondTabbedPane.setModel(otherTabbedPane.getModel());
```